# sort data by specific order sequence (mysql)

Tags: mysql

So, let say I have this data

```
id | value | group
1  | 100   | A
2  | 120   | A
3  | 150   | B
4  | 170   | B
```

I want to sort it so it become like this

```
id | value | group
1  | 100   | A
3  | 150   | B
2  | 120   | A
4  | 170   | B
```

there will be more group than that, so if I the data ordered the group like (A,C,B,D,B,C,A), it will become (A,B,C,D,A,B,C)

Comment: What is the logic behind this sort order? Letters in order, A - Z, one at a time, and then start again, until no letters are left? What makes you pick one A over another A? Remember that database rows have no order to them, so I guess that choice is based on the `id`? One last burning question: WHY?

Comment: To @KIKOSoftware 's question, why is `1  | 100   | A` before `2  | 120   | A`? Because of the `id` or because of the `value`?  What if they have the same value?

Comment: the 'value' or the 'id' doesn't matter here. the data sorted by the 'group'. so if the 'group' unique data is (A,B,C,D), then it should return data in that order.

Comment: So `2 | 120 | A` can come before `1 | 100 | A`?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yes. only 'group' column order matters

Comment: What version of MySQl are you using?

Comment: @RajatS.Subedi  im still using mysql that bundled with xampp. ver 5.6

Answer (score 1):

You can add a counter column to the table, which will be used to sort the table:

```
select t.id, t.value, t.`group`
from (
  select t.id, t.value, t.`group`,
  (select count(*) from tablename 
   where `group` = t.`group` and id < t.id) counter
  from tablename t
) t
order by t.counter, t.`group`
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tepsKDUsr31rvAjRCZEZDJ/1).
Results:

```
| id  | value | group |
| --- | ----- | ----- |
| 1   | 100   | A     |
| 3   | 150   | B     |
| 2   | 120   | A     |
| 4   | 170   | B     |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this as

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
ORDER BY 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY `group` ORDER BY `group`), `group`
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, is there an OVER in MySQL now?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware screen shoot attached

Comment: Yes, I [found it in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html).